# Проблема с автогенерируемыми ID в таблице SQlite

Tags: java, база-данных, sqlite

Добрый день, в своём приложении сделал функцию удаления элементов, в ней происходит удаление записи из таблицы SQlite. Таблица у меня создаётся так

```
getDataStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '" + title + "' ('title' text, 'url' text, 'id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);");
```

В ней как вы видите есть автогенерируемый ID типа int. При удалении элемента из таблицы я хочу чтобы все эти ID перегенерировались в меньшую сторону. Т.е. вот у меня допустим таблица Phones и в ней 3 элемента и у каждого есть id, имя и номер

1 User1 123

2 User2 321

3 User3 213

---

Если удалить User2 с id 2, то получится

1 User1 123

3 User3 213

---

А мне нужно чтобы получилось вот так вот

1 User1 123

2 User3 213

---

Можно ли как-то так сделать?

Comment: а какой смысл вы преследуете?

Comment: У меня создаются объекты с полями, которые инициализируются на основе id базы данных

Comment: но также у вас будут одинаковые поля, нет?

Comment: @Komdosh почему же, у таблицы уникальные id у каждой записи, значит и поля каждого объекта будут уникальными

Comment: ну так вы удалите, и обновите id, значит у следующего вставляемого элемента будет тот же id, что и при инициализации предыдущего

Comment: @Komdosh Может я неправильно понял. Да, когда я удаляю элемент, то я буду бегать циклом по всем элементам начиная от номера удалённого элемента и до конца таблицы и менять значение каждого на  - 1.  Вот, ну а когда добавлю новый элемент, то он будет просто на единицу больше последнего элемента, вроде всё гармонично и правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выполнить такой запрос:

```
UPDATE tablename SET id = id - 1 WHERE id > deletedId
```

где `tablename` - название таблицы, а `deletedId` - id удалённого элемента

Comment: Это то что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @Komdosh Вы бы хоть заодно пояснили в ответе, почему так лучше не делать, а то он ведь сейчас уйдет довольный в полной уверенности, что так и надо...

Comment: @Yaant а что не так?